# Error deserializing Avro message - java.nio.HeapByteBuffer cannot be cast to class java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, avro

I'm using Confluent schema registry and Avro. Data was ingested to kafka using a JDBC connector which uses an SMT for creating proper avro schemas. Problem occurs during deserialization using SpecificAvroSerde. I've got plenty of similar cases and they all work great. So in general the approach of ingesting data, generating avro schema and consuming in stream processors using avro works. The difference with this case is that record contains an array (kind of master/detail record). Below a simplified version of the schema:

```
{
  "namespace": "io.confluent.base.model",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Test1",
  "fields": [
      { "name": "opt_identifier",      "type": [ "null", "string" ],"default": null },
      { "name": "opt_amount",          "type": [ "null", { "type":"bytes", "logicalType":"decimal", "precision":31, "scale":8 }], "default": null},
      { "name": "arr_field",           "type": ["null", { "type": "array",

                                       "items": {
                                         "name": "TestTest1",
                                         "type": "record",
                                         "fields": [
                                             { "name": "opt_identifier_",      "type": [ "null", "string" ],"default": null },
                                             { "name": "opt_amount_",          "type": [ "null", { "type":"bytes", "logicalType":"decimal", "precision":31, "scale":8 }], "default": null}
                                           ]
                                       },
                                       "default": [] }],
                                       "default": null}

    ]
}
```

The schema is compiled using avro maven plugin. Both, connector and sonsumer are using same avro jar versions. The exception I receive is

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 79
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.read(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:409) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:114) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:88) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroDeserializer.deserialize(SpecificAvroDeserializer.java:66) ~[kafka-streams-avro-serde-7.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroDeserializer.deserialize(SpecificAvroDeserializer.java:38) ~[kafka-streams-avro-serde-7.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:58) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:176) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:304) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:960) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addRecordsToTasks(TaskManager.java:1000) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollPhase(StreamThread.java:914) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:720) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:583) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:555) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.nio.HeapByteBuffer cannot be cast to class java.math.BigDecimal (java.nio.HeapByteBuffer and java.math.BigDecimal are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at io.confluent.base.model.TestTest1.put(TestTest1.java:416) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.setField(GenericData.java:818) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:139) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:247) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readRecord(SpecificDatumReader.java:123) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readArray(GenericDatumReader.java:298) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:183) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:136) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:247) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readRecord(SpecificDatumReader.java:123) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:187) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153) ~[avro-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.read(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:400) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.0.1.jar:na]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

I can read the same message using GenericRecord and all fields are there. Hence the avro record got serialized correctly.

My current understanding:

- The problem is linked to logical types
- The same logical type is deserialized at the master level (e.g. `opt_amount`) without problems
- The field `opt_amount_` however throws the exception hence I suspect that this nested detailed record `TestTest1` is not used in the same way as the master record `Test1`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be using `Specific` things if it's going to convert that byte buffer into a `BigDecimal`, now it's using `Generic` and trying to cast.

Comment: Absolutely, approach for reading avro objects from a stream is via
`final SpecificAvroSerde<Test1> testSpecificAvroSerde1 = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
    final Map<String, Object> props = this.kafkaProperties.buildStreamsProperties();
    testSpecificAvroSerde1.configure(props, false);` I only mentioned `Generic` to say, that I've tried and I can read the avro message.

Comment: I was talking about the stacktrace, e.g. `GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion`.

Comment: Got it - yes, couldn't agree more. Hence my comment - `nested detailed record (TestTest1) is not used in the same way as the master record (Test1)` but don't know how to enforce that. Logical types don't get considered correctly which then is leading to a cast exception in the specific record `public void put(int field$, java.lang.Object value$)`. Both classes are there and seem to be used. But for the detail part (i.e. in the array) the handling of logical types doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with AVRO internals. This PR will solve your issue once merged.  https://github.com/apache/avro/pull/1721